# How to display Group column on the left after setColumnState()?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am using Ag-grid to display data on my website. I want to allow a user to modify the view state (change column ordering, group rows, filter, etc); save that modified state; restore it later. I know this is standard functionality, and I am following the official example here: https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/column-state/#save-and-apply-state

Like the example, my code uses `const savedState = gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnState();` to get/save the column state. And later, `gridOptions.columnApi.applyColumnState({ state: savedState });` to restore the state.

The problem I am having is that if a user groups rows, the "Group" column moves to the far right when the column state is restored. It starts on the left when first grouped (which is what I want), but then moves to the right when restored (which is not what I want).

**How do I get the Group column(s) on the left after setColumnState()?**

I see the same undesired behavior in the official example. To illustrate:

1. go to the example link posted above
2. group by some field (Sport, in this example)
3. "Group" column auto-populates at far left (which I want)
4. Click: Save State. Reset State. Restore State.
5. The restored state now shows the "Group" column at far right (which is not what I want)

[image: 1 - before - "Group" column at far left (good)]

[image: 2 - after - "Group" column at far right (bad)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the behavior you are describing is a BUG and it has been fixed in the current nightly build version of AG Grid. So, you will need to wait until the next release (probably 25.2.0).

I know this doesn't help, but at least you won't keep beating yourself up trying to find a way to fix it. What you could do instead, for the time being, is to apply the state and then move the Grouped Column to the left.

```
gridOptions.columnApi.moveColumns(['ag-Grid-AutoColumn'], 0);
```

See: https://plnkr.co/edit/Kg4UPNA8aWL6QRgi

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! It's not ideal, but I'll look to test your proposed workaround - this will probably be good enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `applyOrder:false` to get the group column on the far left.

```
function restoreState() {
  if (!window.colState) {
    console.log('no columns state to restore by, you must save state first');
    return;
  }
  gridOptions.columnApi.applyColumnState({
    state: window.colState,
    applyOrder: false, // Make it false here
  });
  console.log('column state restored');
}
```

Here's a live example: https://plnkr.co/edit/LnViTPw082x0Y9sw?preview

Comment: Thanks! Though I'm not quite sure that's exactly what I need. I believe `applyOrder: false` will suppress **all** ordering changes? So if a user reorders columns, that won't be applied? I just want to preserve column ordering exactly as setup / displayed, including the "Group" column at far left, and any other column order changes the user may have entered.

Comment: Their implementation they wrote "auto group columns are re-created so deferring syncing with ColumnState". So, they don't put the auto group columns right away even if it's the first element of the colState array, rather at the end after putting all the other columns.

Comment: When they internally call the `applyOrderAfterApplyState`, they apply the order based on reordered `colState` which puts the auto group columns at the end.